# Setting alarm using calendar.getTimeInMillis() not working

Tags: android

Trying to fire up an alarm at a specific time, like this:

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR, 17);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);   
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, mAlarmSender);
```

Doesn't seem to be working. I'm logging `onCreate()` in my `Service` and it doesn't seem to be getting called ever.

**EDIT** - I tried switching to `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17)`, which I believe is the right way to do it because that's the 24 hr hour.

But it still isn't working... ;)

**EDIT** It's working now. I just jumped the gun a bit. Apparently the alarm isn't 100% exact.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Calendar object must be set to `(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY)` as opposed to `(Calendar.HOUR)` when you're using a 24 hr hour.

Comment: I'm facing same problem even after setting 24 hours format. Can u please suggest what's wrong with this ?

Answer (score 0):

Use like,

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 17);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 54);

AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)getContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);   
alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(), 30*1000, mAlarmSender);
```